# How to run one function or command in background in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron

I have one table which stores activity points of an activity.This list will be reset at the end of every quarter i.e. 1st day of Jan, April, July, Oct. So for that I have write one function which will run in background. So I used whenever gem for that.

So just to test I wrote following code :

```
gem 'whenever', :require => false
```

Then run "bundle install"

In schedule.rb :

```
every 2.minutes do
   #runner "Activity.demo"
   #rake "my:rake:task"
   #command "/usr/bin/my_great_command"
   command "echo 'you can use raw cron sytax too'"
end
```

Then :

```
whenever --update-crontab
```

Then started rails server but I doesn't understand where I will see the output : "you can use raw cron sytax too"

after starting the server in my terminal there is no output line showing the output : "you can use raw cron sytax too".

Comment: When you run `command` you open a temporary shell session - the command will appear in there, then the session will be closed.  You would see it if you ran it in the console, but if it's running inside your rails server then it won't be visible anywhere else.  It would be better to log it instead, then you could see it in your log file.

Comment: Ok. Thanks :) . 
But now I want to run this on 1st day of Jan, April, July, Oct. So instead of "every 2.minutes do" what command/code I have to write.

Comment: That's a totally different question.